# Have x round down to the nearest specified numeric value from series?

Tags: r

Wondering how x can round down to the nearest below value based on a separate numeric series (y). This is what I had in mind.

Let's say x is in 5s

```
> y
[1]  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
```

And y from a different object is equal to

```
> x
[1] 39
```

I'd like to see it round down to the nearest lower specified value from y

```
> x
[1] 35
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `findInterval`/`cut`

```
y <- seq(5, 45, 5)
x <- 39
y[findInterval(x, y)]
#[1] 35
```

With `cut` :

```
y[cut(x, y, labels = FALSE)]
```

Comment: I really like how easy it is to specific the range and pattern

Answer (score 4):

You can use %/% and multiply it by y (if you set y to be your multiple, e.g. if 5's):

```
y <- 5
x <- 39
(x %/% y) * y
```

If you must use a vector of length > 1 for y then you could use a few different functions like `max()` or `tail(..., 1)` to get the largest or last value in y:

```
y <- seq(0, 50, 5)
tail(y[x > y], 1)
max(y[x > y])
```

Note that `x > y` is creating a logical vector which is being used for a linear search, returning a vector of the values of y less than x and passing that to the function.

Comment: Wow okay, that one's handy